# call for action in zendframework

Tags: php, zend-framework

i am new to zendframework i try to run the sample quickstart
if i give the url without /pubilc it dosn't work 
but if i add the /public i get the frist html page
when i send the from to get the next page i get error
The requested URL /QuickStart/public/extract was not found on this server.
please how do i start whihout the public in the url

Comment: @moti You may want to learn more about webroot folder. Then you may have not asked the same. Sorry to say its not really a zend-framework specific question.

Answer (score 1):

Your document root configuration, probably in Apache, should end ..../QuickStart/public/ and inside that directory are the .htaccess and index.php files.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough detail to say for sure, but it looks like you put the "public" folder in your web root.

ZF needs only the files **from** the public folder inside the web root, while the rest are placed outside - higher up in the folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

The quickstart is written assuming that you set up an Apache Virtual host which points to the public/ directory.

If you can't do that, then try my tutorial: http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial which doesn't make that assumption.

In all cases, it is very important that you have mod_rewrite enabled for your Apache server along with AllowOveride All, so that .htaccess files work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your document root to public/ directory.

If you are on a shared server that might not be possible. In that case, use the following .htaccess file from [Lorenzo Alberton](http://www.alberton.info/zend_framework_mod_rewrite_shared_hosting.html):

Here it is:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
```

Pu it inside your document root.